# error fecha en api c# SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, api

tengo el siguiente codigo en GestorCedula.cs

```
DateTime fecha_nacimiento = dr.GetDateTime(4);
```

en Cedula.cs se creo public `DateTime fechaNacimiento { get; set; }`

en la base de datos SQLSERVER creo fechanacimiento como datetime se muestra hora y fecha correctamente sin embargo a la hora que cargue https://localhost:44358/api/Cedula quiero que solo se vea la fecha sin la hora que debo hacer

```
 while(dr.Read())
                {
                    int id = dr.GetInt32(0);
                    int num_cedula = dr.GetInt32(1);
                    string nombres = dr.GetString(2).Trim();
                    string apellidos = dr.GetString(3).Trim();
                    DateTime fecha_nacimiento = dr.GetDateTime(4);
                    string lugar_nacimiento = dr.GetString(5).Trim();
                    int estatura = dr.GetInt32(6);
                    string sexo = dr.GetString(7).Trim();
                    string tipo_sangre = dr.GetString(8).Trim();



                    Cedula cedula = new Cedula(id, num_cedula, nombres, apellidos , fecha_nacimiento,lugar_nacimiento,estatura,sexo,tipo_sangre);

                    lista.Add(cedula);
                }
```

Comment: Si no necesitas el la parte del tiempo, puedes dejar la columna como `date`. Alternativamente, tal vez hagas costumbre leer la documentación oficial cuando tengas dudas, ahí puedes leer [cómo dar formato a las fechas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: El tipo Date no existe

Comment: El tipo [Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) sí existe si estás utilizando SQL Server 2016, o posterior. Ya que no existe un tipo de dato Date en C#, tu mejor opción es darle el formato deseado según el link de la documentación que pasé anteriormente, si es que quieres leerla...

Comment: el tipo Date no existe en c# por eso lo cree como datetime Date fecha_nacimiento = dr.GetTime(4); me sale que no existe

Comment: *quiero que solo se vea la fecha sin la hora que debo hacer*. Cuando dices eso, a qué te refieres con "sólo se vea"... Dónde? En la API? en el Front End? En la base de datos? En GitHub?

Comment: en la api y en el front